# When screen size is small enough, the third item in list moves to second row to the right rather than left

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an unordered list that is horizontal. However, when the screen size is below a certain resolution, the third item in the list (currently there are only 3) moves to the second line like its supposed to. However, the item is to the right side, under the second item rather than under the first. Here is what i mean:

Normal: 
item1 item2 item3 
Smaller screen: 
item1 item2 
          item3

I have `float:left` set on the list items. How do can i move the third item to the left.

BTW, this only happens in FF and IE, Chrome displays it the way i want.

HTML:

```
<div class="presskit cf" id="logos">
    <h2>
        Logos</h2>
    <hr />
    <ul>
        <li class="logoItem">
            <a href="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/Catapult-Logo-051413-RGB-Clear-Background.zip" target="_blank"><img src="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/Catapult-Logo-051413-RGB-Clear-Background.png" /></a></li>
        <li class="logoItem">
            <a href="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/CatapultLogo1Color.zip" target="_blank"><img src="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/CatapultLogo1Color.png" /></a></li>
        <li class="logoItem">
            <a href="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/CatapultLogoWhite.zip" target="_blank"><img class="whiteLogo" src="/Catapult/media/catapult_media/press_kit/logos/CatapultLogoWhite.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
```

CSS

```
 #zoneB, #zoneC, #zoneD { max-width: 1024px; margin:0 auto; font:normal 21px "proxima-nova-n4", "proxima-nova", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#434343; }
ul { list-style: none; -webkit-padding-start:0px; }
li { float: left; }
h2 { clear:both; }
#leaderBiosList { width:100%; }
.presskit a:hover { color:#f57d3d; }
.presskit a { color:#f57d3d; text-decoration:none; display:block; }
.presskit h2 { font-size: 33px; font-weight: normal; padding-top:2%; width:33%; }
.logoItem { list-style:none; display:inline; }
.logoItem img { max-width:100%; }
.whiteLogo { background-color: #333; }

.cf:before, .cf:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }
.cf { zoom: 1; }

#leaderBios { height:20%; }

@media all and (max-width: 520px){
  .presskit h2 { font-size: 33px; font-weight: normal; width:100% }
  .presskit li { float:left; margin-bottom:4%; width:100%; }
  .leaderList { width: 100%; margin:2% 5% !important; }
  .logoItem { max-width:90%; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 521px){
  .presskit h2 { width: 33% }
  .presskit li { display:inline; margin-right:4%; margin-bottom:4%; }
  .presskit .downloadsList li { width:40%; }
  .presskit .leaderList { width: 33%; margin-right: 15%; }
  .logoItem { max-width:45%; margin-right:2%; }
  #logos ul { clear:both; }

}

@media all and (min-width: 720px){
  .presskit .leaderList { width:28%; margin-right:4%; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px){
  .presskit .downloadsList li { width:30%; }
  .presskit .leaderList { width:20%; margin-right:4%; }
  .logoItem { max-width:25%; margin-right:6% !important; }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code? Thanks!

Comment: Added html of the particular section and all the css

Comment: Are all of the images the same size? If not, the wrapping may not work as cleanly as expected. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kX8FE/1/.

Comment: yes they are all the same size. Its the same image just in different colors.

Comment: your code seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6KrXE/

Comment: lol, Float! because inline is too mainstream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of styling the li directly, I removed the li css and styled #logoItem and that seems to work in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/62jdT/3/

```
 ul {
     list-style: none;
     -webkit-padding-start:0px;
 }

 h2 {
     clear:both;
 }
 #leaderBiosList {
     width:100%;
 }
 .presskit a:hover {
     color:#f57d3d;
 }
 .presskit a {
     color:#f57d3d;
     text-decoration:none;
     display:block;
 }
 .presskit h2 {
     font-size: 33px;
     font-weight: normal;
     padding-top:2%;
     width:33%;
 }
 .logoItem {
     float: left;;
     width: 200px; 
     height: 20px; 
     background: #999;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;

 }
 .logoItem img {
     max-width:100%;
 }
 .whiteLogo {
     background-color: #333;
 }
 .cf:before, .cf:after {
     content:"";
     display: table;
 }
 .cf:after {
     clear: both;
 }
 .cf {
     zoom: 1;
 }
 #leaderBios {
     height:20%;
 }

@media all and (max-width: 520px){
  .presskit h2 { font-size: 33px; font-weight: normal; width:100% }
  .presskit li { float:left; margin-bottom:4%; width:100%; }
  .leaderList { width: 100%; margin:2% 5% !important; }
  .logoItem { max-width:90%; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 521px){
  .presskit h2 { width: 33% }
  .presskit li { display:inline; margin-right:4%; margin-bottom:4%; }
  .presskit .downloadsList li { width:40%; }
  .presskit .leaderList { width: 33%; margin-right: 15%; }
  .logoItem { max-width:45%; margin-right:2%; }
  #logos ul { clear:both; }

}

@media all and (min-width: 720px){
  .presskit .leaderList { width:28%; margin-right:4%; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px){
  .presskit .downloadsList li { width:30%; }
  .presskit .leaderList { width:20%; margin-right:4%; }
  .logoItem { max-width:25%; margin-right:6% !important; }
}
```

Not that I changed some specs like background, width and height just for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, i took the styling you have for .logoItem and only used the height property and set it to the height of the image. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using display inline when you need to follow normal flow. You might think you solve problems with float, but you are creating more than you solve.

All you have to do is

```
li { display: inline; }
```

Here's your list with inline:
http://jsfiddle.net/kX8FE/2/